# Why SetTextColor changes also the background of the entire StaticEdtBox

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, win32gui

I'm trying to change the text color whenever i receive `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

[image]

```
 LRESULT ProcessWindowMessage(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ UINT uMsg, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
        {
            switch (uMsg)
            {
            case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
                ::SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(m_color.red, m_color.green, m_color.blue));
                ::SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
                return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
            }
            
            return m_orgWndProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

As you can see, the color of 'Just a test' was changed, but with it, the background of the entire box was also changed.

I've tried returning almost all `GetStockObject()` combinations including

`return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND + number)`

&

```
GetCurrentObject((HDC)wparam,OBJ_BRUSH)
```

I've to say, that these commands manipulated the color of the background somehow, but never matched the default gray value used to be.

what am i missing here?

Comment: You really should post SSCCE...

Comment: `GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND + number)` is incorrect. You'll want to use `GetSysColorBrush()`. But there's a better way to get the default behavior: [just call `DefWindowProc()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/05/9274857.aspx) and return what it returns after doing your DC manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't try

```
return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
```

As Mark Ransom commented, that would not erase the background if you set the new text.

You should use:

```
return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(CTLCOLOR_DLG);
```

as was suggested earlier.

Comment: That might not work if there's old text that needs to be erased. It all depends on whether the dialog underneath gets redrawn.

Comment: I don't think `CTLCOLOR_DLG` works if you have Visual Styles enabled, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773178(v=vs.85).aspx